# How to generate this fly out effect with jquery?

Tags: jquery, effects

I go to [this URL](http://www.obout.com/flyout/flyout.aspx), and saw a very good fly out effect by javascript.

I generally generate this kind of effect using jquery transfer like this way:

```
<script>
$( "div" ).click(function() {
    var i = 1 - $( "div" ).index( this );
    $( this ).effect( "transfer", { to: $( "div" ).eq( i ) }, 1000 );
});
</script>
```

so I am looking for right code or sample web site, from where I can get the jquery fly out effect just like the link I have given here.

Comment: why not just click the download button on the page you've linked to?

Comment: you can try the [jquery easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) with your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Tooltip()](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) function of Jquery UI Library.

Comment: tooltip container is not appearing the way effect i have show through the link. what could be the logic behind that.